# "The request URI is not valid" - Unable to access analytics data in SAP ByD

Tags: odata, sap-business-bydesign

I have a data source in SAP Business ByDesign (ByD). The data source is exposed via OData. When I click on the data source documentation, I come to an HTML page with some additional information, which has a section "Integration Information". Under that section, there is a link to OData Read Service. When I click that link I get back this:

```xml
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"> 
  <code>005056B402651ED09CAE1EC98CFF8C4F</code>
  <message xml:lang="en">The request URI is not valid.</message>
</error>
```

The URI looks like this:
`/sap/byd/odata/analytics/ds/Proprju05.svc`. Why is that not valid?

The full URL is like this:
`https://my12345.sapbydesign.com/sap/byd/odata/analytics/ds/Proprju05.svc`

How can I access the data source vie the API? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I posted this question in the SAP forum as well. An SAP employee responded that I'm getting back this error because my use does not have the right permission. He mentioned that I need a 'technical user' to access these APIs. Now I'm waiting for a technical user. Will update this thread as soon I got my `technical user`.

Answer (score 2):

This error message appears when the request is made with the credentials of a business user. After executing the request with the credentials of a technical user, it worked! [here is a link](https://help.sap.com/viewer/66e9a9081a7b40e38c8604d6617d0311/CLOUD/en-US/fae295bbb8c54f14ab5a559a04ed0e22.html) to a document how to create the technical user and how to expose the data via Odata.
My question in the SAP forum you can finde [here](https://answers.sap.com/questions/13450125/sap-byd-the-request-uri-is-not-valid.html).